# Deep link in sms content in iOS 9

Tags: ios, sms, deep-linking

I had integrated deeplink in myApp, it work ok now when input deeplink in safari, but now I have problem when detect deeplink in sms content, I define my deeplink with format like this:

> myapp://login 
>   myapp://home

If I using my device and send text sms: `myapp://login` into another iPhone with iOS9, I see my device can detect deeplink but in another device, it cannot.

But in iOS 10, both device send & receive can detected. Who know why this happen and can fix this?

Here is my sms in iOS 9.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom URI schemes are not universally recognized as active links, and behavior will differ (as you've discovered) based on device, OS version, and the app in which you're posting the link. Also, if the app is not installed on a device, the link will lead to an error message when the corresponding app is not installed, even if it is recognized as a link.

For this reason, custom URI scheme links are not a good way to handle this requirement. Apple introduced Universal Links in iOS 9 as a way to work around this, but they also have limitations. You should investigate link routing services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links.